# why this vector space is not isomorphic to its double-dual

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, duality-theorems

let $V$ be the vector space of all sequences of real numbers which are
eventually $0$, that is $ V=\{s=(a_1,a_2, . . .) | \exists N$  such that $a_N = a_{N+1} = · · · = 0\}$.

We know the natural linear map $V → V''$ is not an isomorphism, where $V''$ is the double dual of $V$, but I am not sure why. Could someone explain this to me, thanks a lot!

Comment: In your last question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450811/show-that-the-dual-space-of-a-subspace-of-v-can-be-identified-with-v we "found" $V'$, in the answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448024/algebraic-dual-of-mathbbr-mathbbn/1448048#1448048 is an example of an element in $V'' \setminus V$.

Comment: @martini Thank you for answering, do you meant $V'=V''\V$?

Comment: No. $V' \ne V''\setminus V$, but in the answer linked above, there is an element in $V''$, that is a linear $V' \to \mathbf R$ given, which is not in the image of the natural map $V \to V''$.

Comment: The natural linear map is always injective. So in your case it is because it is not surjective, as @martini said.

Comment: @martini still no sure what that element in $V''$ but not in the image of the natural map is? can you give me more hint. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have seen in [your last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1450811/show-that-the-dual-space-of-a-subspace-of-v-can-be-identified-with-v), that $V'$ can be identified with the space $\def\R{\mathbf R}\def\N{\mathbf N}\R^\N$ of all real sequences, via:
$$ (b_n) \mapsto \sum_n a_n b_n, \quad a \in \p, b \in V $$
We will construct an element of $V''$, that is a linear map on $\R^\N$, that does not lie in the image of the natural map. Let $c \subseteq \R^\N$ denote the subspace of converging sequences, and let $\ell \in (\p)'$ be a linear map such that $\ell\colon c \ni (a_n) \mapsto  \lim a_n$ (such a linear map exists by the axiom of choice: choose any basis of $c$, extend to a basis of $\R^\N$, define $\ell$ by linear extension). Suppose $\ell$ were represented by some $b \in V$. Let $e^k \in c$ denote the sequence $(\delta_{kn})_n$, then 
$$ \ell(e^k) = \lim_n \delta_{kn} = 0 $$
Hence 
$$ b_k = b(e^k) = \ell(e^k) = 0$$
So $b =0$, but $\ell\ne 0$. That is $\ell \in V''\setminus V$.